# Gradient Button Crashed when Removing Gradient

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, cagradientlayer

So I'm new at learning Swift and I'm having trouble with removing the button gradient background, technically I am able to "remove" it but it's not stable and crashes if tapped multiple times. My guess it has something to do with the sublayer not being removed "safely" but I looked around and just can't figure it out.

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitleColor(.systemBackground, for: .selected)
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 0
        sender.applyGradient(colors: [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.5098039216, green: 0.8431372549, blue: 0.5254901961, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.3058823529, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.3215686275, alpha: 1) ], radius: 10)
    } else {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 1
        sender.layer.sublayers!.remove(at: 1)   // this not stable, cause crash if trigger repeatedly
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIButton {
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor], radius: CGFloat = 0, startGradient: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0), endGradient: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = radius
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startGradient
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endGradient
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give your CALayer a name this way you can find the index of your layer before removing it:

```
extension UIButton {
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor], radius: CGFloat = 0, startGradient: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0), endGradient: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 1)) {
        // check first if there is already a gradient layer to avoid adding more than one
        if let gradientLayer = layer.sublayers?.first(where: {$0.name == "gradient" }) as? CAGradientLayer {
            gradientLayer.cornerRadius = radius
            gradientLayer.colors = colors
            gradientLayer.startPoint = startGradient
            gradientLayer.endPoint = endGradient
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        // if not found create a new gradient layer
        } else {
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.name = "gradient"
            gradientLayer.cornerRadius = radius
            gradientLayer.colors = colors
            gradientLayer.startPoint = startGradient
            gradientLayer.endPoint = endGradient
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitleColor(.systemBackground, for: .selected)
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 0
        sender.applyGradient(colors: [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.5098039216, green: 0.8431372549, blue: 0.5254901961, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.3058823529, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.3215686275, alpha: 1) ], radius: 10)
    } else {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 1
        if let firstIndex = sender.layer.sublayers?.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == "gradient" }) {
            sender.layer.sublayers?.remove(at: firstIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this might be the longest and most changes required but it works! I can't get it to crash anymore! You're are a life saver! Was pulling my hairs out trying to figure it out and looking at the solution, it's definitely way more advance than my current level. It appears, naming the layer and removing the said layer is the safest way to approach this, I see many new techniques and code to learn here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you are trying to remove something that's not present forcefuly, check if it's present and then try to remove it. Here's how:

```swift
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitleColor(.systemBackground, for: .selected)

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 0
        sender.applyGradient(colors: [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.5098039216, green: 0.8431372549, blue: 0.5254901961, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.3058823529, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.3215686275, alpha: 1) ], radius: 10)
    } else {
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 1
        if sender.layer.sublayers?.count > 1 {
            sender.layer.sublayers?.remove(at: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x32f366b27ab8)`

Comment: and somehow you can't `sender.layer.sublayers?.count`, Xcode gives this `Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'`, making it into `let sublayers=sender.layer.sublayers, sublayers.count > 1` seems to silent it