# How to put a gradient in a background button witch contains a system image?

Tags: swift, uibutton, gradient

I have a button with a system image:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ampouleButton: UIButton!
```

in the viewdid load, i put this:

```
let ampouleButtonConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(
            pointSize: 30,
            weight: .regular,
            scale: .large)
        
        let ampouleButtonImage = UIImage(
            systemName: "lightbulb",
            withConfiguration: ampouleButtonConfig)
        
        ampouleButton.backgroundColor = Theme.gold03 // i need to put here a gradient
        ampouleButton.setImage(ampouleButtonImage, for: .normal)
        ampouleButton.tintColor = Theme.blanc
        ampouleButton.layer.cornerRadius = ampouleButton.frame.height / 2
        ampouleButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        ampouleButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        ampouleButton.layer.shadowOffset =
            CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        ampouleButton.alpha = 1
```

instead of the background color, i need to put a gradient.

i tested this but it didn't work:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = self.ampouleButton.bounds
            gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        ampouleButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: Use `ampouleButton.setBackgroundImage`.

Comment: Try doing it with button's layer and a `CAGradientLayer` object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093932/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus i put the UIButton extension, and i add this in the view controller with my code:
ampouleButton.applyGradient(colors: [Theme.bleu!.cgColor, Theme.softBlue!.cgColor], radius: 1, startGradient: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5), endGradient: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0))
but the button appears like a square instead of a circle, and the lightbulb disappears

Comment: @LeoDabus the bulb disappeared, and i need it. for the square i put self.ampouleButton.frame.height / 2 in  the radius

Comment: @matt the setBackgroundImage make disappear the bulb systemName image

Comment: Call applyGradient funcation in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method. 

ampouleButton.applyGradient(colors: [Theme.bleu!.cgColor, Theme.softBlue!.cgColor], radius: self.ampouleButton.frame.height / 2 , startGradient: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5), endGradient: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0))

Comment: @RajaKishan the bulb disappeared, and it hasn't. i need a solution where the bulb is displayed. 
With Leo's solution, you can put a text and it works. but i already had a solution like this. i need a solution where the bulb is displayed with a gradient in the background of the button

Comment: Okay, Is button is appear or nothing is appear ?

Comment: @With leo's solution the button appears with the gradient. but the bulb disappeared, because the bulb is considered like a button background

Comment: Actually button image goes behind the layer. try this UIButton class and set all other property inside the class.

class GradientButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.applyGradient(colors: [Theme.bleu!.cgColor, Theme.softBlue!.cgColor], radius: self.frame.height / 2 , startGradient: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5), endGradient: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0))
        if let imgView = imageView {
            self.bringSubviewToFront(imgView)
        }
    }
}

Comment: Or you can do manually add this code after applying the gradient.

        if let imgView = ampouleButton.imageView {
            ampouleButton.bringSubviewToFront(imgView)
        }

Comment: @RajaKishan your solution works. i tested it. thank you. put it in this post like a solution or i will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the button image goes behind the layer. Try this:

```
extension UIButton {
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor], radius: CGFloat = 0, startGradient: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0), endGradient: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 1)) {
        // check first if there is already a gradient layer to avoid adding more than one
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.cornerRadius = radius
            gradientLayer.colors = colors
            gradientLayer.startPoint = startGradient
            gradientLayer.endPoint = endGradient
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

And in the viewDidLoad put:

```
ampouleButton.applyGradient(colors: [Theme.bleu!.cgColor, Theme.softBlue!.cgColor], radius: self.ampouleButton.frame.height / 2, startGradient: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5), endGradient: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)) 
if let imgView = ampouleButton.imageView { ampouleButton.bringSubviewToFront(imgView) }
```

Find applyGradient function from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093932/2303865