# UIKit - adding layer effect to button removes image

Tags: ios, swift

I have a "fake" check box that I made using UIButton and:

```
var mCheckState: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if mCheckState == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I create this layer style to add shadow/highlight edge:

```
contentHorizontalAlignment = .left;
contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0);
setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControl.State.normal)
setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.85, green: 0.70, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)

layer.backgroundColor = globalColorCG_white_background
layer.shadowColor = CGColor(gray: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
layer.shadowRadius = globalButtonRadiusShadow * 0.75
layer.cornerRadius = globalButtonRadiusShadow
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -6.0,height: -8.0)

layer2 = CALayer(layer: layer)
layer2!.backgroundColor = globalColorCG_white_background
layer2!.shadowColor = CGColor(gray: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
layer2!.shadowOpacity = 0.1
layer2!.shadowRadius = globalButtonRadiusShadow * 0.5
layer2!.cornerRadius = globalButtonRadiusShadow
layer2!.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 6.0, height: 8.0)
layer2!.frame = layer.bounds
layer.insertSublayer(layer2!, at: 0)

showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
```

...the image no longer renders. What should I add/fix to get the image to render again? :- )

Extra code for info:

```
    let checkedImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.square")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(systemName: "square")! as UIImage
    var mIsCheckBox = false
    var mCheckState: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if mCheckState == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
                //self.bringSubviewToFront(checkedImage)

            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
                //self.bringSubviewToFront(uncheckedImage)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65246437/14733292

Answer (score 0):

You can bring to front your image

```
class ButtonSubclass: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        /**
         Set other button property and layers.
         */
        
        if let imgView = imageView {
            self.bringSubviewToFront(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm not sure, I'm getting 
                self.bringSubviewToFront(checkedImage)
> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Comment: I've added extra code to main post, you can see how I set images/etc

Comment: What is self?? self is button? I’m UIButton subclass? Or view controller? self is UIButton subclass then put same code as I given in ans

Comment: Ah yes, self is button, this is clas myButton : UIButton{}

Comment: Then add this after layer code.  if let imgView = imageView {             self.bringSubviewToFront(imgView)         }

Comment: Hmm, if I add that line of code after showsTouchWhenHighlighted 
I get > Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImageView?' and Circular reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `layer2` below the button's ImageView layer.

So change this line:

```
layer.insertSublayer(layer2!, at: 0)
```

To this:

```
layer.insertSublayer(layer2!, below: imageView!.layer)
```

You may want to check the button's imageView isn't nil and in cases where it is just add as you have already:

```
if let imageViewLayer = imageView?.layer {
    layer.insertSublayer(layer2!, below: imageViewLayer)
} else {
    layer.insertSublayer(layer2!, at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Raja Kishan, it worked for me

```
        // bring button's image view to the front, self here is UIButton
        if let imageView = self.imageView {
            self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: this is almost exactly the same as their code. why not suggest an edit to their answer instead?