# myView.removeFromSuperview() don't delete my line on myView, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, line, removefromsuperview

I have made a greenView:

```
static func createRectView(
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
    width: Float,
    height: Float,
    color: UIColor,
    transparency: Float
) -> UIView {
    let viewRectFrame = CGRect(
        x: CGFloat(x),
        y: CGFloat(y),
        width: CGFloat(width),
        height: CGFloat(height)
    )
    let retView = UIView(frame:viewRectFrame)
    retView.backgroundColor = color
    retView.alpha = CGFloat(transparency)
    return retView
}
let greenView: UIView = createRectView(
    x: 50,
    y: 110,
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    color: .green,
    transparency: 1
)
view.addSubview(greenView)
```

I have drawn a line on greenView:

```
func getPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: pointDef5)
    return path
}

func createLine(on view: UIView) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil 
    shapeLayer.path = getPath().cgPath
}

createLine(on: greenView)
```

I have removed and added greenView:

```
greenView.removeFromSuperview()
view.addSubview(greenView)
```

I see my old line on absurd greenView!
How delete my line from my greenView?

greenView + line = forever? I don't know how delete a line

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `greenView` is created once and then added to `self.view`. Removing and re-adding this view does not change the view.

The line in your code is added as a sublayer on `greenView`. To remove the line, you must remove the sublayer.

For example, try this:

```
greenView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
```

Comment: view.layer?.sublayers?.removeAll()   it doesn't work - error

Comment: @SwiftLilu give a name to your view setting it’s layer name property. This way if you need to delete it you can search which subview has its layer name and remove it. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093932/2303865)

Comment: @Leo please write in more detail :-( I want to delete stupid line from my greenView!

Comment: The link above does exactly what you need with a gradient layer. Just do the same with your CAShapeLayer

Comment: @LEO can you write CODE please

Comment: @Ely ======> view.greenView.sublayers.removeAll() ====>  Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'greenView' ====> EROR

Comment: @SwiftLilu I corrected my code.

Comment: @Ely it worked! SUPER!!! Ely - I love you!!! Thank you!